# Appending Two Strings in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, intel

We've learned only a touch (by touch I mean nothing in class, only theoretical talk of how registers work) of assembly in school and my professor wants us to do something in assembly a little harder than adding two integers. I've been doing a bunch of research and have come up with some code. I am using Microsoft Visual Code on a Linux VM. From my understanding, the code puts `input1` into ECX, then puts `input2` into ECX, then this essentially appends IF the length of `input1` is at least 10 bytes. Not entirely sure how this is working. If I use less than 10 bytes for the first input I get the next input printed on a new line.

I've been trying to understand how [variable] and variable, value vs. address if I understand correctly, fit into this and have played around with reserved byte variables. I'm not asking for my project to be done, but I feel like I'm blindly trying this as opposed to without direction. Thanks in advance guys!

`section .text`

```
global main        ;must be declared for using gcc
extern printf      ;C library used to print
extern exit        ;C library used to exit
extern scanf       ;C library used to input user entry
```

`main:                  ;tell linker entry point, called main due to C library usage`

```
;Reads prompt message          
mov eax, 4         ;system call number (sys_write)
mov ebx, 1         ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov ecx, prompt1   ;message to write called prompt
mov edx, len1      ;message length
int 0x80           ;call kernel

;Accept user input
mov eax, 3         ;system call number (sys_read)
mov ebx, 0         ;file descriptor (stdin)
mov ecx, input1    ;variable to read into, i.e. input
mov edx, 25        ;input length
int 0x80           ;call kernel


;Reads prompt message          
mov eax, 4         ;system call number (sys_write)
mov ebx, 1         ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov ecx, prompt2   ;message to write called prompt
mov edx, len2      ;message length
int 0x80           ;call kernel

;Accept user input
mov eax, 3         ;system call number (sys_read)
mov ebx, 0         ;file descriptor (stdin)
mov ecx, input2    ;variable to read into, i.e. input
mov edx, 25        ;input length
int 0x80           ;call kernel


 ;cld
mov al, 0
mov ecx, 50
mov edi, input3
repne scasb
dec edi
mov ecx, 2
mov esi, input4
rep movsb
int 0x80

;Display user input
mov eax, 4         ;system call number (sys_write)
mov ebx, 1         ;file descriptor (stdout)
mov ecx, input1    ;message to write
mov edx, 50        ;message length
int 0x80           ;call kernel



call exit
```

`section .data`

```
prompt1 db  'Please enter your first string: ', 0xa  ;string to print for user input
len1    equ $ - prompt1                              ;length of string prompt 

prompt2 db  'Please enter your second string: ',0xa  ;string to print for user input
len2    equ $ - prompt2                              ;length of string prompt        

input3: times 10 db  0                               ;variable input is of 10 bytes, null string terminated
input4: times 1  db  0
```

`section .bss`

```
input1 resb 50
input2 resb 25
```

Comment: Well, that seems like a strange approach. I would think you would want to put the address of the *nul-terminating* character (end of string 1) in `EDI` and the beginning of string 2 in `ESI` and then `movsb` until `ESI` is zero. (you need to ensure the memory reserved for string 1 is sufficient to hold `string 1 + string 2`) Essentially you are just copying string 2 to the end of string 1.

Comment: Also beware `"I am using Microsoft Visual Code on a Linux VM"` - that if that VM is WSL, then assembly is hit or miss (mostly miss) because WSL isn't a full VM.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I appreciate the response David, like I said, we haven't even really looked at assembly code, only just registers and the basics of hello world. So I just have very limited knowledge, I''ll try what you mention and report back. Also I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Another question for you, would I be using SCASB to find the null terminating character in the string? I did that and then copied over input2 to input1 at the null string, accounting for string length, but it still isn't cooperating. Is this the route you would have gone?

Comment: Yes, you can use [scansb](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/scas:scasb:scasw:scasd) to scan to the end of string1 so that address is in EDI, then [movsb](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq) to appeand all the bytes from string 2 in ESI. Bookmark [x86 and amd64 instruction reference](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html) and use it every time you use a system call. (great reference)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sorry to bug you again man, I've tried using some code inbetween the second Accept user input and Display user input, edited in above, I feel like I'm on the right track, but just can't get it to do what I want it to do. Potential suggestions?

Comment: Do you know how to write such a program in C? That will help you.

Comment: @DylanShaw - Why is `input3` put in `EDI` before `repne scasb` and not `input1`? Why is `input4` put in `ESI` before `movsb` and not `input2`? I see `input3` is a 50-byte buffer, but where is `input4` declared?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Apologies, I forgot I changed that part of the code and have reflected the change above. I tried playing around with different types of variables to see if it could product the result I was looking for. I could write a program like that in C, I'll give it a shot tomorrow when I have some more time. Thank you so much again for the help dude.